# Dog ate my blueberry bushes

Tags: shrubs, container-gardening, blueberries

We got a new puppy and she would chew everything is there something I can do to save my babies. [image][image]!

Comment: rabbits chewed my blueberry bushes to the ground and they came back nicely in the spring.

Comment: Train the dog to chew the rabbits who will otherwise chew your blueberries.

Comment: I’m sure you know this but you have taken the first step in having a dog. The blueberries were sacrificed against their own will and died a sad, meaningless death. They just wanted to be sweet to you and instead they went out getting eaten by an animal intellectually incapable of appreciating them. There is no fate worse than being killed by a dog. You’re whole existence wiped out by the animal manifestation of a total lack of sophistication, the vulgar representation of everything humans are not. 

That said the rabbit fence stuff around them will work.

Answer (score 1):

Cut off the chewed ends with sharp secateurs to leave a clean cut - I can see growth buds in a few places, so probably they will regrow. You may need to snip off any upper parts which are obviously dead after growth begins. Then you need to find a way to stop the dog chewing everything...